# How to add EPPlus Nuget package into my exe

Tags: c#, epplus-4

I added the Nuget EPPlus package to my program and now that everything works perfectly I export the .exe but it errors out with the following:

[image]

My program folder where the .exe normally resides does contain the files for epplus but appreantly it is not within the complied program.

The epplus dll does exist:

[image]

Comment: Try it in Release Mode. Typically for File Not Found errors you use a tool ProcessMonitor and work out which file it cant find, where its looking and put the DLL where it is expected.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy  - In VS 2017 Community version I went to Build >  Configuration Manager > Selected "Release" from the configruation drop down > Close. Then rebuild. and then from the folder structure pulled the exe from the bin\relase folder and pasted on the desktop to try, and I get the same message as the one above (the one in the terminal window)

Any other tips? I keep finding this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-KK7bmo1AM) that might help but shouldnt it simpler when including a Nuget package with the release .exe program?